# Оформить афоризм

Tags: нормы-языка

Если в текст включён афоризм, обязательна ли ссылка на источник, или достаточно указать автора?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что афоризмы оформляются так же, как цитаты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В научной работе желательно и ссылку оформить, и в кавычки заключить, а вот в художественном или публицистическом тексте вовсе необязательно. Если вы хотите подчеркнуть, что это именно афоризм и "мнение редакции может не совпадать с точкой зрения автора", то заключить в кавычки стоит. А если этого желания нет, то можно пользоваться как любым фразеологизмом, так как бумага не краснеет, независимо от того какой Цицерон это сказал первым.